# Remove duplicates from lists in columns

Tags: python, list, hash

I have two columns, Col_A and Col_B, in a dataframe, df.

[image]

```
Col_A                   Col_B
[1.222, 1.222, 1.333]   [cla:pl:dr, cla:pl:dr]
[]                      [clp:dp, xr.ld, xr.ld]
[1.29.1, 1.1, 1.1]      [ru:pun, ru:pun, hm:dm]
```

I want to remove duplicated values in ea. list of ea. row for Col_A and Col_B as shown below.

[image]

`type(df['Col_A'][0])` returns `list`

Examples I've tried return unhashable type errors. Ways I've tried to avoid this error to no avail include:

```
df['Col_A'].map(lambda x: tuple(set(x)))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: Copy pasted data.

Comment: Please copy/paste your data, don't paste pictures of it

Comment: This code runs fine on my end

Comment: It turns out to be that my list values were not a type that was hashable. I just converted them to string values. Now it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like You're using string as data.

```
 data = {'col_A': [['1.222', '1.222', '1.333'], [], ['1.29.1', '1.1', '1.1']] ,
         'col_B': [['cla:pl:dr', 'cla:pl:dr'], ['clp:dp', 'xr.ld', 'xr.ld'], ['ru:pun', 'ru:pun', 'hm:dm']] }

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 df['col_A'] = df['col_A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
 df['col_B'] = df['col_B'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

OutPut DF

```
       col_A                 col_B
0   [1.222, 1.222, 1.333]   [cla:pl:dr, cla:pl:dr]
1   []                      [clp:dp, xr.ld, xr.ld]
2   [1.29.1, 1.1, 1.1]      [ru:pun, ru:pun, hm:dm]
```

OutPut DF(after removing duplicates)

```
    col_A           col_B
0   [1.222, 1.333]  [cla:pl:dr]
1   []              [clp:dp, xr.ld]
2   [1.29.1, 1.1]   [ru:pun, hm:dm]
```

Comment: Close, definitely lists but I needed to convert the values inside of the lists to strings.

Comment: @purple_plop, Values inside the list are strings, otherwise it is no possible to create this df, right